Spring boot Oauth2 not automatically refreshed from refresh token
I have a basic Oauth2 setup that is not automatically renewing the authorization token when it expires despite an available and valid refresh token.
Updated with excerpts from controller and service.  Logic flow

MVC request to index
get token from client registry
Call service method
For each pilot(child)
Make call to REST API for pilot details using RestClient.get() with token passed from Controller.  The REST API is a separate Oauth2 Resource Server Spring Boot project using the same keycloak instance as the Oauth2 Client Spring Boot project.

Any suggestions as to the cause and how to fix?
Spring boot version: 3.2.5
application.yaml
      security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            provider:
              keycloak:
                issuer-uri: ${keycloak-issuer}
            registration:
              keycloak-confidential-user:
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                client-name: a local Keycloak instance
                client-id: ${keycloak.id}
                client-secret: ${keycloak.password}
                provider: keycloak
                scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access

WebSecurityConfig.java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain clientSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
            http.oauth2Client(withDefaults());
            http.logout(withDefaults());
            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(ex -> ex
                    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());
            // @formatter:on
            return http.build();
        }
    }

Controller.java
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository clientRepository;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOidcUser principal,
                        Authentication auth,
                        HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                        Model model) {
        String token = getEaToken(auth, servletRequest);
        model.addAttribute("pilots",
                pilotService.getPilotListForUser(UUID.fromString(principal.getName()), token));
        return "pilot/list";
    }
    
    private String getEaToken(Authentication auth, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = clientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(
                "keycloak-confidential-user", auth, servletRequest);
    
        if (authorizedClient == null) {
            log.warn("Authorized client could not be loaded\nauth[{}]\nservlet[{}]", auth, servletRequest);
            return null;
        }
    
        String token = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        log.debug("eaAuthToken is null [{}]", token == null);
        return token;
    }

Service.java
    @Override
    public List<PilotListInfo> getPilotListForUser(UUID userId, String eaAuthToken) {
        List<PilotListInfo> pilots = pilotRepository.findByEveAssistUser_UniqueUserOrderByNameAsc(
                userId, Pageable.ofSize(10));

        if (eaAuthToken != null) {
            for (PilotListInfo pilot : pilots) {
                PilotPublicDto singlePilot = getSinglePilotDetails(pilot.getEvePilotId(), eaAuthToken);
                if (singlePilot != null)
                    pilotMapper.partialUpdateDetails(singlePilot, pilot);
            }
        }
        return pilots;
    }

    @Override
    public PilotPublicDto getSinglePilotDetails(Long evePilotId, String eaAuthToken) {
        ResponseEntity<PilotPublicDto> publicData = eaApiRestClient.get()
                .uri(ESI_CHAR_PUBLIC.formatted(evePilotId))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer %s".formatted(eaAuthToken))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(PilotPublicDto.class);
        if (publicData.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful())
            return publicData.getBody();

        log.warn("unable to get public data for pilot with Eve Pilot Id [{}]", evePilotId);
        return null;
    }


debug screen capture showing active Oauth2AuthorizedClientManager has both access and refresh token.  Also shows authorizedClientProvider to handle the refresh token.


Tokens are refreshed when getting the authorized client from the repo if the access token expired (or will in the next minute). Are you trying to use an authorized client or are you expecting that a Spring application proactively refreshes the tokens for all the authorized clients it manages?

Expecting the token to be refreshed when RestClient.get() is executed.  See above for updates

You should be using the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager (or ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager if you where using a WebClient in a reactive application) which refreshes tokens when the access token has expired (or will within the next minute).
// This can be auto-wired in a Spring OAuth2 client servlet
private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

@Override
public Optional<String> getBearer(String registrationId) {
    final var authentication = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).orElse(ANONYMOUS);
    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(registrationId).principal(authentication).build();
    final var authorizedClient = Optional.ofNullable(authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest));
    final var token = authorizedClient.map(OAuth2AuthorizedClient::getAccessToken);
    return token.map(OAuth2AccessToken::getTokenValue);
}

Note that instead of defining such a helper function in your @Controller, you could configure your RestClient with a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
P.S.
You could find this starter of mine useful for getting RestClient instances already configured with the right ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
Using this starter, you can even get an auto-generated implementation of an @HttpExchange interface, if you defined one for the service you consume (I usually get these interfaces generated from the OpenAPI spec, itself generated from the sources of @RestController with @RequestMapping).
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-rest</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
</dependency>

@HttpExchange(accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface PilotApi {
    @GetExchange(url = "/list")
    List<PilotListInfo> getPilotListForUser();
}

@Configuration
public class RestClientsConfig {
    @Bean
    PilotApi pilotApi(SpringAddonsRestClientSupport restSupport) {
        // binds to com.c4-soft.springaddons.rest.client.pilot-api properties
        return restSupport.service("pilot-api", PilotApi.class);
    }
}

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      rest:
        client:
          pilot-api:
            base-url: http://localhost:8080/pilot
            authorization:
              oauth2:
                oauth2-registration-id: keycloak-confidential-user

With the above, a PilotApi bean is auto-magically generated, with a RestClient configured with a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor using  the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager and the client registration ID you specified! All you have to do is injecting it in your @Controller.
You can try something very similar live with:
git clone https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons.git
cd spring-addons/infra
docker compose up -d

Then:

with your favorite IDE, start the resource-server_with_ui project in debug mode
set a breakpoint in AuthorizedClientBearerProvider
browse to http://localhost:8080/ui/greet
authenticate as brice/secret
wait at least one minute (the access token lifespan is set to 2 minutes and the refresh happens only if the token has expired or will in the next minute)
refresh the browser tab, you should have a new access token in your debugger tools


I am already using that bean, see updated controller above.  I will look into your suggestion about configuring RestClient directly and the spring-addons starter.

I overlooked your code and thought you were getting the token from the @AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOidcUser principal in the controller signature (was mistaken by your 2. get token from Authentication object, when you actually get it from the authorized client repo). Sorry about that.

No need to apologize for trying to help!!  WRT ClientHttpRequestInterceptor based on my reading of documentation / examples, this would be an alternate method to obtain the token and/or set the Authentication header.  I don't see this helping with automatically refreshing an expired token.  Correct?

Fun fact, if you were using my "experimental" starter, you wouldn't have had the problem <:oD what I use there is the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, not the OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository. Updating my answer.

I'll look at this over the next couple of days.   Quick question ... you specifically call out using the Reactive stack.  Does the non-Reactive stack auto-renew the token?

All the code samples in the answer are on the synchronized stack: SpringAddonsRestClientSupport builds a RestClient (not a WebClient which is built by SpringAddonsWebClientSupport) and, with the provided configuration properties, pre-configures this RestClient with a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor using the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager bean (not a ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager one). My starter looks at what is on the classpath (WebMvc or WebFlux) to create only the right beans (reactive or synchronized).

Plus, the resource-server_with_ui project I linked for running in debug mode is a servlet. To my knowledge Synchronized and reactive stacks behave the same regarding tokens refreshing.
